# One cell with multiple lines

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table that has some cells spanning across multiple lines, like this:[image: Table that I want]

(I used print screen on my table and then edited it to show how I want it).

I have been searching around and didn't find a way to do it, though I have seen similar problems but couldn't apply their solution to mine.

This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Funções e conexões do conector X1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{X1} &\textbf{Descrição} &\textbf{Função} \\
    \hline
    1   &C      &Saída digital 1 \\
    \hline
    2   &NA     &a relé \\
    \hline
    3   &Dl1        &Entradas digitais \\
    \hline
    4   &Dl2        &optoacopladas \\
    \hline
    5   &COM 1,2    &1 e 2 \\
    \hline
    6   &Dl3        &Entrada digital 3 \\
    \hline
    7   &COM3           &optoacoplada \\
    \hline
    8   &Al1 +          &Entrada analógica 1 \\
    \hline
    9   &Al1 -      &diferencial \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to just not draw full horizontal lines when you want to combine rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Funções e conexões do conector X1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
      \hline
      \textbf{X1} &\textbf{Descrição} &\textbf{Função} \\\hline
      1   &C      &Saída digital 1 \\\cline{1-2}
      2   &NA     & a relé\\\hline
      3   &Dl1        &Entradas digitais\\\cline{1-2}
      4   &Dl2        & optoacopladas\\\hline
      5   &COM 1,2    &1 e 2 \\\cline{1-2}
      6   &Dl3        &Entrada digital 3 \\\cline{1-2}
      7   &COM3           &optoacoplada \\\hline
      8   &Al1 +          &Entrada analógica 1 \\\cline{1-2}
      9   &Al1 -      &diferencial \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Funções e conexões do conector X1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cll}
      \toprule
      \textbf{X1} &\textbf{Descrição} &\textbf{Função} \\\midrule
      1   &C      &Saída digital 1 \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      2   &NA     & a relé \\\midrule
      3   &Dl1        &Entradas digitais \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      4   &Dl2        & optoacopladas \\\midrule
      5   &COM 1,2    &1 e 2 \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      6   &Dl3        &Entrada digital 3 \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      7   &COM3           &optoacoplada \\\midrule
      8   &Al1 +          &Entrada analógica 1 \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      9   &Al1 -      &diferencial \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The second tabular shows how to reformat the table in accordance with the guidelines set out in `booktabs` (or some of them anyway).

[image: Tabulars]

Or you could remove the partial horizontal lines altogether if you took this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Funções e conexões do conector X1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cll}
      \toprule
      \textbf{X1} &\textbf{Descrição} &\textbf{Função} \\\midrule
      1   &C      &Saída digital 1 \\
      2   &NA     & a relé \\\midrule
      3   &Dl1        &Entradas digitais \\
      4   &Dl2        & optoacopladas \\\midrule
      5   &COM 1,2    &1 e 2 \\
      6   &Dl3        &Entrada digital 3 \\
      7   &COM3           &optoacoplada \\\midrule
      8   &Al1 +          &Entrada analógica 1 \\
      9   &Al1 -      &diferencial \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: Most minimal]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Actually, I'm not sure. I can't tell. Is it obvious that the text in the right-most column goes together (1&2, 3&4, 5&6&7, 8&9) or might it be read as belonging on each line individually?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've added it as an example so the OP can judge what's best. The 3 line combination I worry about especially since the 2nd line starts with a capital. (I don't know why but it is not my language so I'm dealing with mere strings.)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for *yours*! And I think providing both options is definitely best here.

Answer (score 0):

The  `makecell` package is just  for multilined cells (whether multirow or not). In addition, just using horizontal lines, as pointed above, loks much better. In addition, using the rule commands from `booktabs` gives some spacing to the cells. I also use the `caption` package: just loading it gives a better vertical spacing between the caption and the table. As another comment, you shouldn't use  the  `center` environment here: it adds its own vertical spacing to the one provided by `table`.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\cellalign}{lc}

    \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
    \caption{Funções e conexões do conector X1}
\begin{tabular}{cll}
    \toprule
    \thead{X1} &\thead{Descrição} &\thead{Função} \\
    \toprule
    1   &C      &\multirowcell{2}{Saída digital 1 \\a relé}\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
    2   &NA  &   \\
    \midrule \addlinespace
    3   &Dl1        & \multirowcell{2}{Entradas digitais \\ optoacopladas}\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
    4   &Dl2        &\\
    \midrule
    5   &COM 1,2    &\multirowcell{3}{\\[-2ex]1 e 2 \\ Entrada digital 3 \\ optoacoplada}\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
    6   &Dl3        & \\
\cmidrule{1-2}
    7   &COM3   & \\
    \midrule \addlinespace
    8   &Al1 +   & \multirowcell{2}{Entrada analógica 1 \\ diferencial} \\
\cmidrule{1-2}
    9   &Al1 -      & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]